# What does it mean to "shff fh nair into knee?"

Tags: terminology, super-smash-bros-series

I was reading a Smash Ultimate combo guide and someone told me that the best Captain Falcon combo is:

> shff fh nair into knee

What on earth are they trying to say? And is it even a real thing?

Are there any other weird acronyms I should know when reading online or listening to commentators?

Comment: It's Gaelic for "but then I took an arrow in the knee".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They were trying to tell you to

> [**S**hort **H**op](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Short_hop) [**F**ast **F**all](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Fast_fall) to land the **F**irst **H**it of [**N**eutral-**Aer**ial](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Neutral_aerial) which will combo into [the **Knee** of justice](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Knee_Smash).

Phew. Wasn't that a mouthful? But damn is it worth it for [the true combo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QlR7.gif)!

There are actually quite a few shorthanded phrases that have been developed for Smash over the years. I've tried to come up with a not-quite-comprehensive list below of acronyms that may be hard to google. I’ve included wiki links where I could find them. You'll hear many of these from tourney commentators as well as written online:

- **AC** - [Auto Cancel](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Auto-canceling)
- **Bair** - [Back Aerial](https://www.ssbwiki.com/back_aerial)
- **BKB** - [Base Knockback](https://www.ssbwiki.com/knockback#Basic_physics)
- **DA** - [Dash Attack](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Dash_attack)
- **Dair** - [Down Aerial](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Down_aerial)
- **DBZ** - When both characters hit each other and are launched at high speed toward the blastzone simultaneously. Usually results in at least one of the two losing a stock. (See [Top 10 DBZ Moments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MiydNxcUh8))
- **DI** - [Directional Influence](https://www.ssbwiki.com/directional_influence)
- **DJ** - Double Jump (using both jumps in quick succession from the ground)
- **DSR** - [Dave's Stupid Rule](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Dave%27s_Stupid_Rule) (used in tournaments for stage picking)
- **Fair** - [Forward Aerial](https://www.ssbwiki.com/forward_aerial)
- **FD** - [Final Destination](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Final_Destination_(SSBU))
- **FF** - [Fast Fall](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Fast_fall)
- **FH** - First Hit (the first [hitbox](https://www.ssbwiki.com/hitbox) of a multi-hit move) or [Full Hop](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Short_hop) (opposite of shorthop) depending on context.
- **JC** - [Jump Cancel](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Jump-canceling) (usually followed by what you're jump cancelling into. ie: JC Up-Smash)
- **JV** - [Winning with a stock with no damage](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Stock#JV) (so if you won with 2 extra stocks, but were at 0%, it's almost as if you had 3 stocks. You "JV 3-stocked" the opponent. See [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/ajhdod/origins_of_jv_stocking/) for the history behind it)
- **KB** - [Knockback](https://www.ssbwiki.com/knockback)
- **KO** - [Knockout](https://www.ssbwiki.com/KO)
- **MU** - [Matchup](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/346100/222207)
- **Nair** - [Neutral Aerial](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Neutral_aerial)
- **OoS** - [Out of Shield](https://www.ssbwiki.com/out_of_shield)
- **PS2** - [Pokemon Stadium 2](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Pok%C3%A9mon_Stadium_2)
- **SD** - [Self Destruct](https://www.ssbwiki.com/self-destruct)
- **SDI** - [Smash Directional Influence](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Smash_directional_influence)
- **SH** - [Shorthop](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Short_hop)
- **Zair** - [Z-Aerial or "Grab Aerial"](https://www.ssbwiki.com/grab_aerial)

Comment: Don't forget that fh means full hop sometimes; not in the op's example, of course, but sometimes. Nice thorough answer, btw.

Comment: @Brandon_J good call! I was probably so focused on the example I didn't think about it. Thanks!

Comment: I used to be a smasher like you, but then I took a Falcon in the knee